# No sound 20.04 with Intel Corporation Device 02c8

Tags: sound, 20.04

Fresh install of 20.04 with Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8 has no sound. This fix did not help. Updated kernel to 5.7 and took a few other steps that helped in older versions. Anyone have this sound card working on 20.04?

Comment: I have this sound card and it has been working for me on 20.04 using kernel 5.4.0-37-generic. That said, I'm getting pops and cracks on my headphones and have been having issues with microphone sound quality (which I what brought me here). Audio worked out of the box so I'm afraid I don't have any steps to suggest for getting yours going.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/hje1z2/no_sound_on_hp_pro_book_have_alsa_and/

Comment: Could you post the relevant output from `sudo lspci -v` and`dmesg | grep audio`?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue for `f0c8`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. All I need to edit a line in `/etc/default/grub` to be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"
```

Then you run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I updated the answer for Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Interestingly, I do get a sound for a couple of seconds, and then it starts to turn down on its own until it goes fully quiet. I've tried so many things and still nada.

Comment: This worked for me on the following configuration:
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"

Comment: Thank you for the solution !