# Dummy Audio on thinkpad t14 amd

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, thinkpad

I'm getting no audio on my thinkpad t14 amd when i go to increase the audio it displays dummy audio which means my audio card isn't getting detected anyone have any fixes?

Comment: Same here. Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.9.

Comment: same kernel to so you know any fix :facepalm: it seems like reloading alsamixer doesn't work

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256825/no-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04-dell-xps-7390-realtek-alc3271-intel-corporation-de fixed the issue for me.

Comment: i tried that, didn't end up working

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why. But like 1 of 4 reboots i have sound. I try a lot of stuff to make it work, but at the end I just run

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

every time I logged in and works.

I have the same machine in ubuntu 20.10 ( upgraded from 20.04 because y need the kernel 5.8 for HDMI support )

My uname

> Linux vili 5.8.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 5 13:24:33 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

For me the following fix worked:

In /etc/pulse/default.pa , find this section :

```
### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

after this section add the following line:

```
load-module module-detect
```

save exit. after reboot, the sound issue should be fixed

I don't exactly know in depth details of what was causing this, but I tried almost all fixes given on all forum in the end only this worked.

I am using kernel 5.8, signed version from ubuntu repository

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be caused by a bug in the package `libasound2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.1)`. [0] A temporarily workaround is to do the following:

`sudo modprobe -r snd_rn_pci_acp3x`
`systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`
`sudo modprobe snd_rn_pci_acp3x` [1]

You have to do it after every reboot. But you can put it in a shell script which you run on every login (automatically). Tested succesfully on a Thinkpad T14 AMD (Type 20UD-CT01WW), with kernel 5.8.0-28-generic.

To run those commands as a script at every login, put those three lines in a file. Copy this file into `/etc/profile.d/`. You'll need to allow the respective user or a specific group to run those modprobe-commands without a password-prompt. To do so, edit you sudoers-file: `visudo` or `vim /etc/sudoers` (or the editor of your choice). To allow a specific user to run the modprobe-command without a password-prompt, add at the very end of this file `username ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/modprobe -r snd_rn_pci_acp3x, /usr/sbin/modprobe snd_rn_pci_acp3x`. Change `username` to your respective user.
Or if you want to allow a specific group to run those commands without a password-prompt (i.e. users within the group `sudo`), add the same line but instead of `username` add `%sudo`.
I needed to add this line to my sudoers-file, otherwise I got stuck after the login (just got a black screen and nothing happened).

It seems there's already a fix for this in the testing-repository. [3]

[0] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1901157 
[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1901157/comments/5 
[2] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1901157/comments/12

Comment: Thank you, this is the only answer that worked for me! I did have to add this afterwards though: sudo alsa force-reload (this command did not work on its own)

Answer (score 0):

After clean installation Xubuntu 20.04 the sound works (also on live USB). After doing an upgrade (apt update + upgrade) the audio breaks... So I made new installation again and I am not going to perform any upgrade until there is a solution for this.

P.s. LCD brightness keys are working only after upgrading the kernel to 5.8