# Configure Intel Corporation Device 02c8 to work on Ubuntu 20.0.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, huawei, pci

I have been trying for the last weeks to get the sound working on my Huawei Matebook D laptop.

```
System:    Host: iason-NBLB-WAX9N Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
           Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HUAWEI product: NBLB-WAX9N v: M1010 
           serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: HUAWEI model: NBLB-WAX9N-PCB-B2 v: M1010 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           UEFI: HUAWEI v: 1.34 date: 06/07/2021 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: QUANTA driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-28-generic
```

The following is the actual PCI device:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
```

I have tried reloading ALSA, updating drivers etc. but none of these work. Currently, when I go to settings a generic input/output device is listed but it does not work. Any suggestions? I cannot use sound through the PCI device, only through bluetooth devices.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1235880/1004020 , https://askubuntu.com/a/1295435/1004020

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/default/grub` file may need to be modified for this to work. Fortunately, it's not too difficult to do:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit the `grub` file with `sudo` and your favourite text editor:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/default/grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Find the line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add this to the end, within the quotes:

   ```
   snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0
   ```

   After the edit, you may see something like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
   ```
3. Save the file and exit the text editor
4. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot

Your system should now properly detect and use the Intel audio device.

Comment: Still not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I wrote 116 words with formatting and detail and you reply with six that has nothing actionable. So ... no. No other suggestions without detailed specifics from your computer in the form of system logs. Further blind suggestions will waste your time and mine.