# Firmware/Bios update and no sound on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bios, firmware

My laptop is a Dell Vostro 5490
After a firmware update that was made from Ubuntu Software Center I have no sound from speakers, although when I use a usb headphones/microphone I get sound.

```
arecord -l
arecord: device_list:276: no soundcards found...
```

```
lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Integrated Sensor Solution
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1339
```

I have tried also to reinstall alsa and pulseaudio but that did not work.

I have tried updating over and over again via Ubuntu software Center but it keeps coming back each time

[image]

For fwupdmgr

```
# fwupdmgr get-devices
Vostro 5490
│
├─BC511 NVMe SK hynix 512GB:
│     Device ID:          3743975ad7f64f8d6575a9ae49fb3a8856fe186f
│     Summary:            NVM Express solid state drive
│     Current version:    11004101
│     Vendor:             SK hynix (NVME:0x1C5C)
│     Serial Number:      SN9AN91721090B50M
│     GUIDs:              71575487-e6fa-52be-a95f-62cd22ec72fc ← STORAGE-DELL-108787
│                         8811e962-e1d5-e811-9f8b-f2801f1b9fd1
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Supported on remote server
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│                         • Signed Payload
│   
├─System Firmware:
│ │   Device ID:          a45df35ac0e948ee180fe216a5f703f32dda163f
│ │   Summary:            UEFI ESRT device
│ │   Current version:    1.3.0
│ │   Minimum Version:    1.3.0
│ │   Vendor:             Dell (DMI:Dell Inc.)
│ │   Update State:       Failed
│ │   Update Error:       failed to update to 0: invalid firmware format
│ │   GUIDs:              f90be13c-2383-47bc-936f-4b7ba031ec69
│ │                       230c8b18-8d9b-53ec-838b-6cfc0383493a ← main-system-firmware
│ │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
│ │                       • Updatable
│ │                       • System requires external power source
│ │                       • Supported on remote server
│ │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
│ │                       • Cryptographic hash verification is available
│ │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │ 
│ └─UEFI dbx:
│       Device ID:        362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590
│       Summary:          UEFI revocation database
│       Current version:  238
│       Minimum Version:  238
│       Vendor:           UEFI:Linux Foundation
│       Install Duration: 1 second
│       GUIDs:            00fe3755-a4d8-5ef7-ba5f-47979fbb3423 ← UEFI\CRT_E28D59CA489BD2AD580F2EA5D62D6A29BB9C02AE5A818434A37DA7FC11DFF9E9
│                         4a6cd2cb-8741-5257-9d1f-89a275dacca7 ← UEFI\CRT_E28D59CA489BD2AD580F2EA5D62D6A29BB9C02AE5A818434A37DA7FC11DFF9E9&ARCH_X64
│                         c6682ade-b5ec-57c4-b687-676351208742 ← UEFI\CRT_A1117F516A32CEFCBA3F2D1ACE10A87972FD6BBE8FE0D0B996E09E65D802A503
│                         f8ba2887-9411-5c36-9cee-88995bb39731 ← UEFI\CRT_A1117F516A32CEFCBA3F2D1ACE10A87972FD6BBE8FE0D0B996E09E65D802A503&ARCH_X64
│       Device Flags:     • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Only version upgrades are allowed
│                         • Signed Payload
│     
└─TPM 2.0:
      Device ID:          a3487e128cf1413519bce8e9a1ab3f5981e61458
      Summary:            UEFI ESRT device
      Current version:    7.2.1.0
      Vendor:             Dell Inc. (PCI:0x1028)
      Update State:       Success
      Update Error:       Updating disabled due to TPM ownership
      GUIDs:              894074d4-d977-5b30-9d19-b2031c86103b ← 0959-2.0
                          ff71992e-52f7-5eea-94ef-883e56e034c6 ← system-tpm
                          7d65b10b-bb24-552d-ade5-590b3b278188 ← DELL-TPM-2.0-NTC-NPCT
                          6f5ddd3a-8339-5b2a-b9a6-cf3b92f6c86d ← DELL-TPM-2.0-NTC-NPCT75x
                          fe462d4a-e48f-5069-9172-47330fc5e838 ← DELL-TPM-2.0-NTC-NPCT75xrls
      Device Flags:       • Internal device
                          • System requires external power source
    
________________________________________________

Devices that were not updated correctly:

 • System Firmware (1.3.0 → 1.23.0)

Devices that have been updated successfully:

 • BC511 NVMe SK hynix 512GB (11001101 → 11004101)
```

If I reboot then I see that BIOS version is on version 1.23.0

I ve booted with live usb either ubuntu 22.04 or 23.04 and I still have Dummy Output and no soundcard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem with the solution provided here

https://askubuntu.com/a/1295435/1072868

Added /etc/default/grub to be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"
```

And then executed

```
sudo update-grub
```