# Audio Problems. Cannot get an analogue output. HDMI only - Dummy Output

Tags: 20.04, sound

I know, this question has been asked a hundred times before. I have tried all of those hundred solutions and nothing works.

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. All I had was 'Dummy Output'. I have done a fresh install of 22.04, same issue. I have upgraded from 20.04, same issue. After installing/uninstalling/editing etc I now have an HDMI/Display port as an option in sound. I have no Display monitor. Reverted to 20.04 to start again. I have HDMI and Dummy only, no analogue, and no way of listening to anything without HDMI speakers.

No option for analogue sound and a laptop without sound is going in the bin.

I am not technically minded -  I use Ubuntu because it works (usually)

OK. If anyone is willing to walk me through this I would appreciate it. I use an IOTA Flo360. Ubuntu 20.04 (but can reinstall with 22.04?? ((rather not, has caused problems on two old machines ((wifi adapter disappeared/display was upside down)) )

A bit vague, I know. Anything you need to know, then ask. If you need info from the terminal then please give me the code to cut and paste. I have used Ubuntu for 10+ years but I have rarely needed to understand anything pre-20.04. It just worked (restricted extras codecs aside)  Since 20.04 LTS I have had to spend a week or so on every machine to render them usable.

Comment: Without 22.04/23.10, I can only suggest exploring `hdajackretask`. Please also provide details about your sound card, perhaps from `lspci` and `aplay -l`

Comment: lspci 
 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 06)

Comment: Not sure that was readable. I will try again.       lspci 

 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 06)   and         aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0                      Hope that helps, thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: hdajackretask says I have an Intel Generic codec and HDMI outputs only.

Comment: Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/a/1235880/1004020 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1295435/1004020 ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try them now

Comment: I tried everything on the first link, a few times now. I have different kernels but I did give it a try. No difference. I couldn't make head nor tail of the second link, I'm afraid I have no idea how to edit as suggested, I'm a copy and paste guy. I can copy what is suggested but I don't know where to paste it or even how. Cheers again. Kelv

Comment: So basically open the file with `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` , and paste `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` then `options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1`. Remove other lines with the same name if you already added any. This does the same thing as the grub option. Fully apply the settings with `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot

Comment: Result from Terminal     sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
[sudo] password for ft: 
sudo: vim: command not found

Comment: Replace vim with nano or another command-line text editor or install it.

Comment: Cheers, managed it with Nano. Same result though, still only hdmi audio.

Comment: So ... currently doing a live install of Ubuntu 23.10.1, just checking it out. I have my sound card back - Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio -   One problem remains; the volume level, even at maximum is so low as to be inaudible. Any ideas on this one?   Thanks people.    ETA - headphones work - low volume but they work.

Comment: You can use `pavucontrol` to set the volume to 200%. Are you sure it's set as speaker and not line out?

Comment: Not sure, no. It's kind of a moot point anyway as the LiveUSB does not give me an option to install. It just boots into a live USB. Am trying a fresh fresh 22.04. now.    Thank you Daniel, I am gonna let you be for a bit, thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, well I think my computer had died. 22.04 couldn't load as my keyboard and mouse stopped working. Managed to install 20.04 again, but the mouse and keyboard stop after a minute or so. I am going to see if I can re-install my windows. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay,, running windows again. It is working.  I will never put a linux OS on a machine again - unless it is a laptop that no longer works. Post 18.04 Linux is a risk. Thanks again. I may try when  the 24.04LTS comes out.